# Python Display Matrix (Nested tuples)

Tags: python, excel, matlab, numpy

I recently started using Python (I come from Matlab) and have been trying to find a way to emulate Matlab's matrix abilities in Python. I discovered Numpy and the use of nested tuples as well as xlrd and they have been very useful but I still couldn't find a way to display that info in a meaningful way. I wrote some code to do it. Thought I'd share in case anybody finds it helpful.

Of course you could easily expand on it, adding special handling for more datatypes, etc.

--Brett

Comment: Do not answer your won question, put everything you need to explain in the OP. And provide an example of input and the desired output so that people could understand your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
def displayTable(data):
    for row in data:
        line = ''
        for col in row:
            if isinstance(col, datetime.datetime):
                line += '{:^15}'.format(str(col)[0:10])
            elif isinstance(col, float):
                if col.is_integer():
                    line += '{:^15}'.format('{:.0f}'.format(col))
                else:
                    line += '{:^15}'.format(str(col))
            else:
                line += '{:^15}'.format(str(col))
        print(line + '\n')
```

Output:

[image]